# Terraform GCP: The resource was not found for an external ip address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create the base VPC network on google cloud platform using terraform on which I could then launch instances, GKE etc, however I end up with the following error message:

```
Error: Error creating RouterNat: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/lol/regions/mars-north1/addresses/39.144.42.123' was not found, notFound
```

This is the minimal terraform code without variables which leads to this state:

```
module "gcp_vpc" {
  count = var.project_type == "aws" ? 0 : 1

  source  = "terraform-google-modules/network/google"
  version = "3.0.1"

  project_id   = var.project_id
  network_name = "${var.project_name}-lol-vpc"
  routing_mode = "GLOBAL"

  subnets = [
    {
      subnet_name           = "${var.project_name}-lol-primary-subnet-${count.index}"
      subnet_ip             = "10.222.0.0/28"
      subnet_region         = var.gcp_region
      subnet_private_access = "true"
      subnet_flow_logs      = "true"
    }
  ]

  secondary_ranges = {
    "${var.project_name}-lol-secondary-subnets" = [
      {
        count         = length(var.public_subnets)
        range_name    = "${var.project_name}-lol-subnet-alias-${count.index}"
        ip_cidr_range = var.public_subnets[count.index]
      },
      {
        count         = length(var.private_subnets)
        range_name    = "${var.project_name}-lol-private-subnet-${count.index}"
        ip_cidr_range = var.private_subnets[count.index]
      },
    ]
  }
}

module "cloud-nat" {
  count = var.project_type == "aws" ? 0 : 1

  source                             = "terraform-google-modules/cloud-nat/google"
  version                            = "~> 1.3"
  project_id                         = var.project_id
  region                             = var.gcp_region
  router                             = "${var.project_name}-lol-router"
  create_router                      = true
  network                            = module.gcp_vpc[0].network_name
  # subnetworks                        = module.gcp_vpc[0].subnets_self_links
  nat_ips                            = google_compute_address.nat.*.address
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "ALL_SUBNETWORKS_ALL_PRIMARY_IP_RANGES"
  min_ports_per_vm                   = "128"
  icmp_idle_timeout_sec              = "15"
  tcp_established_idle_timeout_sec   = "600"
  tcp_transitory_idle_timeout_sec    = "15"
  udp_idle_timeout_sec               = "15"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "nat" {
  count = var.project_type == "aws" ? 0 : length(var.public_subnets)

  name    = "${var.project_name}-lol-eip-nat-${count.index}"
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.gcp_region
}

output "gcp_nat_ips" {
  value = google_compute_address.nat.*.address
}
```

However, I can see the external ip address `39.144.42.123` on the GCP web console. Can someone please help with where should I be looking at to solve this issue? Is it terraform, the terraform provider or GCP?

Comment: try this [ routing_mode = "REGIONAL" ] instead "GLOBAL"

Comment: I second @Mahboob, Cloud NAT is expecting a `Regional` IP resource, so is `39.144.42.123` a regional resource (in the same region as your Cloud NAT) ?